# How to wire a gfi to a switch which controls another outlet

Tags: light, pool

I am going from 20 amp breaker to a gfi.i know thats my line then i want to go to a switch. Which will go to a outlet for lights

Comment: Does the outlet need GFCI protection?  Because if it doesn't, your best play is to leave the "For Wizards Only" warning tape on the Load terminals, and just connect all wires to Line. Then, it just wires like a normal outlet. See the instructions for how to hook 2 wires to a Line screw.

Comment: The 2nd outlets are for lights around the deck  and wanted them to be able to turn off. But didnt want to run a 2nd line

Answer (score 1):

As you said, incoming hot and neutral go to the LINE terminals of the GFCI.

The new hot (black wire) goes from the hot/LOAD terminal on the GFCI to the switch. Another hot goes from the switch to the new outlet. The new neutral (white) goes from the neutral/LOAD terminal directly to the new outlet (it actually needs to follow the same path as the hot: use a cable or conduit from the GFCI to the switch and another from the switch to the outlet and splice the neutrals together).

The ground (green/bare) wire needs to go from the source to all of the GFCI, switch and outlet.

Do not interconnect the hot or neutral downstream of the GFCI with any others.

Since you are on a 20 amp breaker, make sure all wiring is 12 gauge or larger. Also make sure the switch is 20A rated. Many switches are 15A rated, which is OK for lights but not for receptacles on a 20A circuit.

Comment: OP will need to affix "GFCI Protected" labels to any other outlets protected off the Line terminals.